# Stored procedure within function failing because of missing values

Tags: php, sql

I can't figure out where my error lies here, but I'm calling this function and sending the 3 required arguments but the procedure is failing at execute.

I added a dump and die statement and it prints all 4 parameters being used in the procedure. One thing I'm concerned about is making sure all 4 things are being properly sent in as strings, as they should all be strings in the procedure.

Maybe it's something else because when I add the 4 param values manually into my IDE they successfully enter into the database. Is there an issue with how I'm sending these values?

```
    function createUser($out2,$email,$access){

        $type = 'web';

        $userStmt = \DB::connection('odbc')->getPdo()->prepare("call schema.insertUser(?,?,?,?)"); 

        $userStmt->bindParam(1, $out2, PDO::PARAM_STR,20);
        $userStmt->bindParam(2, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR,140);
        $userStmt->bindParam(3, $access, PDO::PARAM_STR, 2500);
        $userStmt->bindParam(4, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);

        dd("Out" . $out2 . "Email" . $email . "Access" . $access . "Type" . $type);
        $userStmt->execute();
    }
```

Dumping $userStmt

```
PDOStatement {#845 ▼
  +queryString: "call schema.insertuser(?,?,?,?)"
  errorInfo: array:4 [▼
    0 => ""
    1 => 0
    2 => " ((null)[0] at (null):0)"
    3 => ""
  ]
}
```

Comment: So, what's exactly happening when you call it?

Comment: I'm part of the procedure uses $type and $access in an HTTPClob to a url and it's getting a 400 and showing empty values for those parameters.

Comment: What happens when you comment out everything and just dump the params?

Comment: that's what I'm doing with dd above, it dumps all 4 things as I would expect

Comment: So, then it's something to do with your database call

Comment: That's what I would think but if I copy those things directly into the database call in an IDE then it works fine. I copy from the error message and past them in with success

Comment: You need to mess with your db connection, it's not working properly

Comment: What do you get if you dump $userStmt?

Comment: @cmac I just dumped it above

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php

Comment: Dump it like this $stmt->errorInfo()

Comment: It dumps exactly the same just without PDOStatement {#845 ▼
  +queryString: "call schema.insertuser(?,?,?,?)"
  errorInfo:

Comment: But it fails at the execute line so that wouldn't work would it?

Comment: Try passing your params through execute function instead of using bind

Comment: The page reloaded without error that time but no record was created

Comment: Put it in a try...catch
try{
// code
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }

Comment: What does that tell you?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be catching anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188231/discussion-between-cmac-and-tom-n).

Comment: While you debug this. You must set: PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE ! This will trap most errors. There are bugs in the mysql drivers that can confuse PDO.